# Any way to explicitly trigger ValidatesOnDataErrors?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I am using ValidatesOnDataErrors in my code, to validate some input. At times I would like to trigger it explicitly, can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're able to do this from the backend here's an example for a textbox and text property:

```
txtName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```